Integral cauchy distriution equals normal distribution?
I'm studying for my midterm and got stuck in a basic probability question. The question is as given below.
Consider Neyman-Pearson criteria for two Cauchy distributions in one dimension
$$p(x|\omega_i) = \frac1{\pi b} * \frac1{1+(\frac{x-a_i}b)^2}, i = 1, 2$$
Assume a zero-one error loss, and for simplicity $$a_2 > a_1,$$ the same “width” b, and equal priors.
(a) Suppose the maximum acceptable error rate for classifying a pattern that is actually in w_1 as if it were in w_2 is E_1. Determine the decision boundary in terms of the variable given.
I found an answer as below but I don't understand the right hand part.
(a) The error for classifying a pattern that is actually in w_1 as if it were in w_2 is:
$$\int_{R_2}^\ p(x|\omega_1)P(\omega_1) dx = \frac{1}2\int_{x^*}^\infty N(\mu_1, \sigma_1^2)dx <= E_1$$
Our problem demands that this error be less than or equal to E_1. Thus the bound on x^* is a functino of E_1, and could be obtained by tables of cumulative normal distributions, or simple numerical integration.
As I wrote above, I don't under stand the right hand part of the given equation. I understood that 1/2 should be at the front because the two distributions have same priors, but not the rest. Can anybody please help? Is integral of cauchy distribution same with normal distribution?
Thank you in advance.
